# How to cut 12 in half and get 7

Tags: lateral-thinking

Here's a puzzle that a teacher told me today:

> How can you cut twelve in half and get seven?

Hint (only if you're stumped):

> Don't let just regular numerals control you

Another Hint

> Notice that I didn't use the math tag

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> Slice XII across the middle to get VII.

I'm pretty sure that's what Quark's answer is facetiously alluding to.

Comment: Yep this is what I wanted. Good Job

Answer (score 66):

Here's a more mathematical answer from a programmer:

> If we use the base 12 numbering system then 12 (in base 12) == 14 (in base 10), and half of that is 7 (in both base 10 and 12).

Comment: Although I think the expected (and now accepted) answer is the Roman Numerical one, I actually like your answer better. +1 from me.

Comment: 12 (in base 12 (in base 10)) :P

Comment: But the body of the question explicitly spells out t-w-e-l-v-e and s-e-v-e-n.

Comment: @200_success In numeration systems (which happens to be my field of study), we often use "eleven" for what is written as "11" in the base we work in, so "twelve" need not be 2*6 always :)

Answer (score 45):

Cut perfectly in half we have a 7 folks!

> [image: Cut perfectly in half we have a 7!]

Answer (score 41):

Slightly different answer:

> 12 is a base ten number. Cut the base in half, and you get 7.
>  (base five) 12 = (base ten) 7

Comment: Now this one is a great way how to think out of the box!

Comment: That's brilliant!

Answer (score 21):

Here's how you can get seven by cutting twelve in half:

> [image]

Comment: I like this, but it's not what I was looking for. And what happens to the extra part of the one?

Comment: That isn't cutting 12 in **half**. Still, nice one!

Comment: Doesn't this make 71?

Comment: Well you do get "a" 7. This is a common puzzle and I wanted to try to be funny instead.

Answer (score 11):

@CoolGuy I disagree that it isn't cutting "12" in half. No matter which of the resulting fragments you take, you get 7.

Lines in PS are to ensure that they are exactly (100/100 pixels above and below guide lines) cut in half.

> [image: 12 / 2 = 7]

Comment: But isn't that 77?

Comment: @Imray Nah, it's just two sevens.  Two sevens are better than one!

Answer (score 11):

This is 12 points:

```
. . . .
. . . .
    . .
    . .
```

Cutting it diagonally from top right to bottom left, we get two sets of 7 points:

```
. . . .
. . .
```

and:

```
  .
. .
. .
. .
```

Comment: Before you comment, try halving a single point.

Answer (score 0):

> Using roman numbering seems to do the trick : 12 is : **XII**, cut it horizontally  and you have **VII** at the top
>
> ```
> /||
> ```
>
> ```
> /\||
> ```

Comment: This has already been answered 3 times

Comment: I feel like at this point it's a running joke.

Answer (score -1):

> 12 = XII

strike through the middle

> the top half now becomes VII
>  VII = 7